# SSMS shortcut to comment/uncomment a specific part of the query?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm looking for an option to comment/uncomment a particular part of the query with the [Slash Star Comment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms178623.aspx) option.

**Scenario:**

While debugging the queries with **N** numbers of `JOIN`s, I comment out each table in the join and its related conditions one by one and find which table causing the issue or wrong data. If the commented table didn't cause the issue, I will uncomment the table and its related condition and try with the next table.

For this purpose currently I manually add [-- comment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms181627.aspx) in front of the particular line or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to comment the entire line, if the select/conditions are in middle of the line, I move the select/condition alone to the next line and add [-- comment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms181627.aspx). If there is no issues with the join, again I undo the changes or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> to uncomment.

Moving the condition to the new line and adding the comment is burden to me, some time it caused bad alignment too.

**Expectation:**

What I want is need some shortcut key to add the `/*` in front and `*/` in end of the selected text.

**Samples:**

The below is the sample case, which my query looks like (in actual it may contain more select columns, tables and conditions).

```sql
SELECT T1.Id, T1.Name, T1.Designation, T1.CreatedDate, 
       T2.AccountName, T3.LinkId, T3.LinkName, T4.OwnershipName
FROM TableOne T1
INNER JOIN TableTwo T2 ON T2.Id = T1.Id AND T2.Name = T1.Name
INNER JOIN TableThree T3 ON T3.Id = T2.Id AND T3.IsActive = 1
INNER JOIN TableFour T4 ON T4.Id = T1.Id AND T4.LinkId = T3.LinkId AND T4.IsActive = 1
WHERE T1.CreatedDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate AND T1.DeletedDate IS NULL
    AND T2.DeletedDate IS NULL AND T3.DeletedDate IS NULL AND T4.DeletedDate IS NULL
```

Here if I want to comment the `TableThree` and its related content in the `SELECT`, `JOIN` and conditions in `WHERE`. I will select the content and press the shortcut key to add the `/*  */` comment separately.

Expected the behavior is:

```sql
SELECT T1.Id, T1.Name, T1.Designation, T1.CreatedDate, 
       T2.AccountName/*, T3.LinkId, T3.LinkName*/, T4.OwnershipName
FROM TableOne T1
INNER JOIN TableTwo T2 ON T2.Id = T1.Id AND T2.Name = T1.Name
/*INNER JOIN TableThree T3 ON T3.Id = T2.Id AND T3.IsActive = 1*/
INNER JOIN TableFour T4 ON T4.Id = T1.Id /*AND T4.LinkId = T3.LinkId*/ AND T4.IsActive = 1
WHERE T1.CreatedDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate AND T1.DeletedDate IS NULL
    AND T2.DeletedDate IS NULL /*AND T3.DeletedDate IS NULL*/ AND T4.DeletedDate IS NULL
```

Answer (score 7):

You can easily do this with [Code Snippets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492130.aspx), something like this will work for your example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <_locDefinition xmlns="urn:locstudio">
        <_locDefault _loc="locNone" />
        <_locTag _loc="locData">Title</_locTag>
        <_locTag _loc="locData">Description</_locTag>
        <_locTag _loc="locData">Author</_locTag>
        <_locTag _loc="locData">ToolTip</_locTag>
        <_locTag _loc="locData">Default</_locTag>
    </_locDefinition>
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>SLASH STAR COMMENT (surrounds)</Title>
            <Shortcut></Shortcut>
            <Description>Surround selected text with slash star comment block /**/</Description>
            <Author>wBob</Author>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>SurroundsWith</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Declarations>
                <Literal>
                    <!--<ID>x</ID><ToolTip>y</ToolTip><Default>z</Default>-->
                </Literal>
            </Declarations>
            <Code Language="SQL">
                <![CDATA[/* $selected$ $end$ */]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Save the file with a `.snippet` extension and follow the instructions from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492130.aspx) to add the snippet to SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).

**Instructions for use**

1. highlight the text you want to surround with the comment block in the query editor
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to summon the 'Surround With' snippets.  Note the comma between the two sequences, it means "press Ctrl+K, *then* press Ctrl+S in quick succession"
3. Select your snippet from the list
4. Your highlighted text is surrounded with the comment block
5. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to Undo - this is the normal windows undo command.  It will remove the comment block as long as you haven't made any other edits.

[image: Code snippets in action]

Comment: It is working, There is `<Shortcut></Shortcut>` node. Is it possible to assign any shortcut to this code snippet? For every time pressing the `Ctrl + K, S` and select this snippet is, again repeating of the work

Comment: It works only 1 time. I then need to re-import the .snippet

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any way to natively do that in SSMS, but this free plugin tool allows that option and so much more

http://www.ssmsboost.com/